# Golang dep unable to resolve dependencies

Tags: kubernetes, godeps, kubebuilder

I am using [kubebuilder](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder) to create kubernetes operator project. After running the project init command described in [quickstart guide](https://book.kubebuilder.io/quick_start.html)

```
kubebuilder init --domain k8s.io --license apache2 --owner "The Kubernetes Authors"
```

`dep ensure` returns with error log given below.

```
Solving failure: No versions of k8s.io/client-go met constraints:
    v8.0.0: Could not introduce k8s.io/client-go@v8.0.0, as it is not allowed by constraints from the following projects:
    kubernetes-1.10.1 from (root)
    kubernetes-1.10.1 from sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@master

    v7.0.0: Could not introduce k8s.io/client-go@v7.0.0, as it is not allowed by constraints from the following projects:
    kubernetes-1.10.1 from (root)
    kubernetes-1.10.1 from sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@master

    v6.0.0: Could not introduce k8s.io/client-go@v6.0.0, as it is not allowed by constraints from the following projects:
    kubernetes-1.10.1 from (root)
    kubernetes-1.10.1 from sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@master
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the latest `kubebuilder` from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder/releases).  It's likely that the dependencies for the version in the quick start are out of date.

It works fine for me with `v1.0.3`

```
~/go/src/github.com $ kubebuilder init --domain k8s.io --license apache2 --owner "The Kubernetes Authors"
Run `dep ensure` to fetch dependencies (Recommended) [y/n]?
y
dep ensure
Running make...
make
go generate ./pkg/... ./cmd/...
go fmt ./pkg/... ./cmd/...
go vet ./pkg/... ./cmd/...
go run vendor/sigs.k8s.io/controller-tools/cmd/controller-gen/main.go all
CRD manifests generated under '/root/go/src/github.com/config/crds'
RBAC manifests generated under '/root/go/src/github.com/config/rbac'
go test ./pkg/... ./cmd/... -coverprofile cover.out
?       github.com/pkg/apis [no test files]
?       github.com/pkg/controller   [no test files]
ok      github.com/pkg/errors   0.207s  coverage: 100.0% of statements
?       github.com/cmd/manager  [no test files]
go build -o bin/manager github.com/cmd/manager
Next: Define a resource with:
$ kubebuilder create api
```